# Phasor Representation of Sinusoidal Forcing Functions

Tags: voltage, ac, passive-networks, phasor

Lets take a phasor **V<sub>m</sub>**<\$\theta\$  which is equivalent to **V<sub>m</sub>cos(\$\omega\$t + \$\theta\$)**

Let us Assume that a forcing function on a network is  **V<sub>m</sub>cos(\$\omega\$t + \$\theta\$) +j V<sub>m</sub>sin(\$\omega\$t + \$\theta\$)**

This can be written as  V<sub>m</sub> e<sup>j(\$\omega\$t + \$\theta\$)</sup>    by Euler's relation

simplifying this gives  **V<sub>m</sub>e <sup>j\$\theta\$</sup>**  .e <sup>jwt</sup>

which further can be written as   **V e <sup>j \$\omega\$ t</sup>**  where **V** is a  defined by V<sub>m</sub>e<sup>j\$\theta\$</sup>

My question is : are  both **V** and  **V<sub>m</sub>**<\$\theta\$  Equivalent?

My book  implies that they are equal.

Correct Me

2nd Question **How are Phasors Complex numbers**?

Answer (score 1):

They are equivalent in that they represent the same sinewave with amplitude \$V_m\$, phase \$\theta\$ and frequency \$\omega\$ (implicit at this level). Mind that, although they are often represented by exponentials, sinusoidal signals are purely *real*. Therefore you always have to take the real part of the exponential form, and that's how you obtain the cosine.

The phasor helps you in expressing the phase as an exponential, therefore making simpler to operate with different signals and reactive components.

Answer (score 1):

> Lets take a phasor Vm<θ which is equivalent to Vmcos(ωt + θ)

You must be careful to keep in mind the full context of phasor analysis

Essentially, when doing phasor analysis, where it is assumed that all sources are sinusoidal of the same frequency, we 'pretend' that the circuit is excited by sources of the form

$$v_S(t) = V_m e^{j(\omega t + \phi)} = V_m e^{j\phi}e^{j\omega t} = \mathbf{V_s}e^{j\omega t}$$

where the *phasor*

$$\mathbf{V_s} =  V_m e^{j\phi}$$

is the **complex constant** that multiplies the unit magnitude time dependent complex exponential term.

It's easy to show that, in the case of a *linear* circuit, all the voltages and currents will have this same time dependence but have differing complex constants.

Thus, we can suppress the time varying component and solve for the voltage and current phasors, adding the time dependence back at the end to arrive at the total solution.

Even though *there are no physical sources of this form*, the 'magic' of phasors is this:  we can take just the real part of the total solution and we have the correct solution for the circuit with sources of the form

$$v_S(t) = V_m \cos(\omega t + \phi) = \Re(V_m e^{(j\omega t + \phi)}) =\Re(\mathbf{V_s}e^{j\omega t}) $$

To summarize, the phasor \$\mathbf{V_s}\$ is the complex constant that multiplies \$e^{j(\omega t + \phi)}\$ and, thus, we can *associate* the phasor with a real sinusoid \$\cos(\omega t + \phi)\$ *if we take the real part of the complex solution in the end*.

This justifies the use of *complex* numbers in the analysis of physical circuits where all voltages an currents are *real* valued.